# Create a custom app action to do a specific task in our app

Tags: android, android-intent, actions-on-google, app-actions

There are some **Built-in-intents** for **app actions** , which are used to perform some tasks. Can we create our own **custom app actions**, which does a specific task in our app.

**For example** :
The app acts as an work manager. It is used to assign each work to the employees present there. I want a custom app action which is used to access this type of app. Some of the queries be like - `"Hey Google , assign the task-3 to employee-4"` , `"Mark task-71 as completed"`,etc. if I say these queries to my **Assistant** , it should be reflected in my app.

Comment: It doesn't fit your use-case exactly, but have you tried using the [actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/#open-app-feature) BII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [app actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/overview) are limited to a [specific set of built-in Intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations) that center around a few topics:

- Food ordering
- Ride sharing
- Finance
- Fitness

  - Exercise
  - Nutrition
  - Health

Comment: What about the "Ok Google, talk to MyApp" option? Then the assistant could play a welcome intent something like "What do you want to do?". I saw examples asking the user to say his favourite color.

Comment: These do not trigger an app that runs on your phone - they trigger a [Conversational Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) that largely run in the cloud.